# Websphere servlet caching by pathinfo

Tags: websphere

I have a servlet, hosted in Websphere v7 that I'd like to cache. The servlet is accessed by either of the following paths

/analysis/abc
/analysis/def

with the servlet itself being mapped to /analysis/ and retrieving the abc or def via pathinfo.

I'd like to cache both URLs (i.e. 2 entries on the dynamic cache) and I've used the following cachespec.xml file:

```
 <cache-entry>
      <class>servlet</class>
      <name>/analysis</name>
      <name>/parser.jsp</name>
      <name>com.at.servlets.EdisonParser</name>
      <name>com.at.servlets.EdisonParser.class</name>      
      <cache-id>
         <component id="" type="pathinfo">
            <required>true</required>
         </component>

         <timeout>180</timeout>
      </cache-id>
  </cache-entry>
```

This works, in that the response is cached. However it only stores one cache entry for both URLs, so I get the same result by hitting either page. How do I tell it to consider both urls as separate entries?

Comment: But you dont have /analysis as name anywhere here. And I've never seen serveral <name> elements in one cache entry. Maybe try to define separate for each of your servlets.

Comment: Edited above. I only have 1 servlet - and according the the red book, multiple name elements are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple `<name>` elements, if the apply to the **same** servlet. Check [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rdyn_cachespec.html?lang=en). Quoting:

> You can specify multiple name elements within a cache-entry if you
>   have different mappings that refer to the same servlet.

I've defined the following `cachespec.xml`:

```
<cache-entry>
      <class>servlet</class>
      <name>servlet.PathServlet.class</name>
      <cache-id>
         <component id="" type="pathinfo">
            <required>required</required>
         </component>
         <timeout>180</timeout>
      </cache-id>
  </cache-entry>
```

It is working fine, as I can see 3 entries in cachemonitor with different contents:

[image]